# In the process of counting the number of supersinguar elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

Let $φ:E→E$ be $q$-th Frobenius map and $φ'$ be it's dual isogeny.
And we define $a$ as $a＝1-deg(1-φ)＋deg(φ)$(what we call trace of frobenius).

Then, My question is ,

**Why $[a]＝φ＋φ'$ ?**

These questions are from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', $p150$.
In the process of counting the number of supersingular elliptic curve over closed field of positive character, I need to use this result.

Comment: Because $[\deg(u+v)]= (u+v)^* (u+v)=u^*u+v^*v+u^*v+v^*u$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626328/